# tabpage - textbox somente leitura

Tags: c#, winforms

Galera boa noite
como vai?
Tenho um form, com uma tabpage, e com alguns textbox, estou tentando implantar no load da pagina, que a propriedade isreadonly esteja como true.

porem não estou conseguindo, estou utilizando o seguinte condigo:

```
private void Comercial_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctl in tabControl1.Controls)

            if(ctl is TabPage)
            {
                ((DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit)(ctl)).ReadOnly = true;
                ((TextBox)(ctl)).ReadOnly = true;
            }

        xtraTabPage1.PageVisible = false;
        xtraTabPage2.PageVisible = false;
        xtraTabPage3.PageVisible = false;
        xtraTabPage4.PageVisible = false;
    }
```

porem ao executar, e retornado o erro:

> Additional information: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage' no tipo 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit'.

Apos comentário do nosso amigo, tentei de novo, mas ainda sem sucesso:

```
foreach (Control ctl in xtraTabControl1.Controls)

            if (ctl is TextEdit)
            {
                ((TextEdit)(ctl)).Enabled = false;
            }
```

Valeu

Comment: Jovem, tem um componente DevExpress aí que muda um pouco de figura teu cenário :-D

Comment: Amigo, mesmo retirando aquele componente, não esta rolando, fiz assim, e tambem naada:

Comment: Tenta usar componentes nativos do .NET no foreach pra ver se funciona... vc precisa de um tratamento diferenciado para componentes do DevExpress

Comment: Hum.. estou utilizando o xtraTabcontrol do DX, vou mudar para o tabcontrol do .net e tentar. Obrigado

Comment: Mesmo verificando se é um textEdit tu faz o cast? Tentou sem o cast? Qual erro devolve?

Comment: Da segunda maneira, ele nao retorna nenhum erro, so que ao executar a a aplicação, os textedit não ficam somente leitura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigos bom dia.
Consegui resolver o problema.

O erro estava que ao fazer o laço estava mencionando o TabControl, porem os controles estão na TabPage.

Segue condigo corrigido:

```
foreach (Control ctl in tabPage1.Controls) 
            if (ctl is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)(ctl)).ReadOnly = true;
            }
```